# IPset and making firewall simple

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, ipset

I've got many rules like:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s IP_LOCAL1 -j SNAT --to-source IP_PUBLIC1
-A POSTROUTING -s IP_LOCAL2 -j SNAT --to-source IP_PUBLIC2
...
...
-A POSTROUTING -s IP_LOCAL100 -j SNAT --to-source IP_PUBLIC100
```

Is there any possibility to make an ipset with declaration IP_LOCAL1:IP_PUBLIC1 and then make only one rule using ipset?

Comment: Just to clarify, you need a permanent 1:1 mapping, so anything with `--to-source $firstip-$lastip` will not do? I don't think you can tie `ipset` to `SNAT` in the way you propose (as they're distinct modules)

Comment: also, are those IP addresses sequential (x.x.x.1 to y.y.y.1, x.x.x.2 to y.y.y.2, etc) or are they random?

Comment: No there ip addresses are random and rather not range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Currently it is not possible to use ipset as SNAT directives.